# Configuring postgresql driver through Spring xml datasource

Tags: java, sql, spring, postgresql

I've been trying to configure the connections made with a postgresql datasource declared in a xml Spring configuration file.

```
<bean id="myDataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbname" />
        <property name="username" value="postgres" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
        <property name="socketTimeout" value="10"/>
    </bean>
```

I know, I shouldn't be using the `DriverManagerDataSource` class from spring, (we will soon move to C3p0 or DBCP) because it's not a real pooling.
I'm trying to set the socketTimeout value of a postgresql connection ( described here https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html ) but of course, "socketTimeout" is not a property of the datasource, so it doesn't work.

Is it possible to do this through the datasource xml's configuration ? Or should I do it somewhere else ? Because the data source manages the connection I don't think I'll be able to do a

```
props.setProperty("timeout",30);
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
```

Can I even do this with the DriverManagerDataSource ? I tried to search, but I didn't find anything usefull, as not a lot of people are really using it.

Comment: That is why there is a `connectionProperties` property which takes a `Properties` element. Just add it to that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thank you M. Deinum, I was able to find how.
Actually, even knowing the property was named "connectionProperties", I didn't found a lot answers (maybe people rarely use it this way ?). So I'm posting it:

```
<bean id="myDataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbname" />
        <property name="username" value="postgres" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
        <!--<property name="socketTimeout" value="10"/>-->

        <property name="connectionProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="socketTimeout">10</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
   </bean>
```

If anyone has a better/more complete answer, I'll check it out ;)