# Spring JPA:PropertyAccessException 1:...MethodInvocationException:.'driverClassName' ... org/postgresql/Driver : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I'm new to Spring Data JPA. I was able to implement the simple solution for normal storing, deleting, finding of the objects/rows in tables of PostgreSQL DB.

I tried an in-memory DB i.e. HSQLDB and it worked fine for me working with it.
However, the problem is when I try to connect to PostgreSQL DB schema.
Please guide me with the solution for this issue as to what could be causing this one problem.

Below is the stacktrace for same :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [spring.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/postgresql/Driver : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:973)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:750)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.spring.btl.pl.controller.UserController.main(UserController.java:17)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [spring.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/postgresql/Driver : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:320)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/postgresql/Driver : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:62)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1489)
    ... 23 more
```

My spring.xml is as below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
        ">

    <!-- Scans for components that will be auto-registered as Spring beans -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.btl.pl" />
    <!-- Scans for repositories that will be auto-registered -->
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.spring.btl.pl.repository" />
    <!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes e.g: @Autowired -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- JPA -->

    <!-- Datasource, that is currently hsqldb (in-memory database). -->
    <!-- <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:datasource" />
        <property name="username" value="sa" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean> -->



 <bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/parulTestDB" />
    <property name="username" value="postgres" />
    <property name="password" value="postgres" />
    <property name="connectionProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="socketTimeout">10</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

    <!-- EntityManagerFactory -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
            p:packagesToScan="com.spring.btl.pl.entity"
            p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
            >
            <!-- <property name="jpaProperty">  
           <props>  
               <entry key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>  
               <entry key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>  
               <entry key="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheProvider"/>  
               <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />  
               <entry key="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="false" />  
               <entry key="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />  
               <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>  
               <entry key="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults" value="false"/>  
           </props>  
      </property>   -->
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                        <!-- <property name="database" value="${jpa.database}" />
                        <property name="showSql" value="${jpa.showSql}" />
                        <property name="databasePlatform" value="${jpa.dialect}" />
                        <property name="generateDdl" value="${jpa.generateDdl}" /> -->
                <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
                <property name="showSql" value="false" />
            </bean>
        </property>

    </bean>

    <!-- Transactions -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

My UserController.java as below :

```
package com.spring.btl.pl.controller;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.spring.btl.pl.dao.UserDao;
import com.spring.btl.pl.entity.Usert;


public class UserController {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:/spring.xml");
        UserDao userDao=ctx.getBean(UserDao.class);
        userDao.saveObject(new Usert(3,"sanjay", "xyz"));
        List<Usert> list= (List<Usert>) userDao.findObject();
        System.out.println(list);
        System.out.println("user object saved");
    }       
}
```

Usert.java i.e. Entity is as below :

```
package com.spring.btl.pl.entity;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table (name="User")
public class Usert {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    public Integer id;
    public String user_name;
    public String description;

    /**
     * 
     */
    public Usert() {

    }


    public Usert(Integer id) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
    }


    /**
     * 
     * @param id
     * @param user_name
     * @param description
     */
    public Usert(Integer id, String user_name, String description) {
        this.id = id;
        this.user_name = user_name;
        this.description = description;
    }
    /**
     * 
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [id=" + id + ", user_name=" + user_name + ", description="
                + description + "]";
    }

}
```

UserDao.java is as below :

```
package com.spring.btl.pl.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.spring.btl.pl.entity.Usert;
import com.spring.btl.pl.repository.UserRepository;

@Component
public class UserDao implements BaseDao  {

    @Autowired
     private UserRepository userrepo;
     private Usert user;


    public void saveObject(Object obj) {
        //Usert user=new Usert();
        user=(Usert) obj;
        userrepo.save(user);

    }


    public void deleteObject(Object obj) {
        user=(Usert) obj;
        userrepo.delete(user);
    }


    public void updateObject(Object obj) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    public Object findObject() {
        List<Usert> userList=userrepo.findAll();
        return userList;
    }

    /*public void deleteObject(Object obj) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        userrepo.delete(user);
    }

    public void updateObject(Object obj) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }*/
}
```

UserRepository is as below :

```
package com.spring.btl.pl.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.spring.btl.pl.entity.Usert;

@Transactional
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<Usert, Long> {


}
```

pom.xml is as below :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>BTL_PL</groupId>
  <artifactId>BTL_PL</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <properties>
        <!-- Generic properties -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>

        <!-- SPRING & HIBERNATE / JPA -->
        <spring.version>4.0.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.data.jpa.version>1.7.1.RELEASE</spring.data.jpa.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.1.9.Final</hibernate.version>
        <hsqldb.version>1.8.0.7</hsqldb.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring-Data-JPA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.data.jpa.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JPA Implementation (Hibernate)-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- IN MEMORY Database and JDBC Driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>${hsqldb.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
             <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
             <version>9.4.1212</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- LOG -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- This plugin is needed to define the java version in maven project. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configuring postgresql driver through Spring xml datasource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34310641/configuring-postgresql-driver-through-spring-xml-datasource)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dataSource should be configured like this:

```
<bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/parulTestDB" />
        <property name="username" value="postgres" />
        <property name="password" value="postgres" />
        <property name="connectionProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="socketTimeout">10</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: hi maciej thanks a lot for your suggestion.
I made changes and am facing another issue currently, i'm compiling this project at Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15) and same is the version of java from command prompt.
Any suggestions from your end for the issue?
I updated logs in the question itself.

Comment: your postgresql driver is to high to Java 1.7. Try an earlier version .. 9.3-1102-jdbc41

Comment: let's say i switch to jdk 1.8 that'd work for me right? with same  version of postresql driver.
btw Thanks maciej, your suggestion for changing the version to 9.3-1102-jdbc-41 resolved the issue.